# Convert VARCHAR to Integer In Hibernate Mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a legacy database which stores many values which should be numeric as CHAR and VARCHAR values.

Normally a VARCHAR or CHAR is mapped to a String. Can I override it to return it as an Integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is no way to do this automatically, you should be able to use a Hibernate [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html)

See: http://i-proving.com/2005/08/03/user-types-in-hibernate